# Moving an Angular2 component to another location

Tags: jquery, angular

I'm having the following, simple angular2 component

```
 @Component({
    selector: 'dynamic-info-template',
    template: '<div id=\"dynInfoTemplate\">dynamic info template<a href="javascript:void(0);" (click)="navigateTo()">Link</a></div>'

})
export class DynamicInfoTemplateComponent {

    constructor(private navigationSvc: NavigationService) {}

    public navigateTo():void{
        this.navigationSvc.navigateTo("/test", 1);
    }
}
```

The challenge now is, that I need to move/reposition this component into another `div` that gets initialized later on by a third party component **(not an Angular2 Component!)**.

Simply copying the `.html()` with jQuery doesn't work (well, it does work, but the events like the `(click)` events wont.

```
$(".targetPopup .contentPane").html($("#dynInfoTemplate").html())
```

I know this whole approach wont win a beautiful code contest, but there is no way around the third party component and as it isn't officially angular2 compatible, I need a "hacky" solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow just 3 steps to make it work

- Import {DynamicInfoTemplateComponent} from'./path from the other component'.
- in @Component use providers:[ DynamicInfoTemplateComponent ].
- in the template in @Component just use

`<dynamic-info-template></dynamic-info-template>`

ie. selector where you want the data to be displayed.

Comment: Hi, thanks, but I think I didn't mention it clearly: the target, where I want to embed the dynamicInfoTemplate into, is not an angular2 component, but simply a dynamically created `<div>` created by some jQuery/javascript library.